# What do we measure using norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Over the course of my studies I have acquired quite rigid notion of distance (probably due to my interaction with Physics). So when studying vector spaces, more specifically $\mathbb {R}^n$, I can't seem to understand the use of norms other than the norm induced by the dot product, this includes norms induced by inner products other than the dot product, other valid norms, etc. I  would like soften this rigid notion of distance, using proper motivation for what norm represents and if it is distance then how so?

Comment: For example, the $L^1$ norm $\| x \|_1 = \sum_i |x_i|$ measures the distance between two points if you are constrained to move parallel to one of the axes at all times. That's why it is sometimes called the "taxicab" metric.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Or "Manhattan metric", because on that island you are famously (mostly) constrained to move around along a rectangular grid. Many other places are like that, but Manhattan won the norm-naming contest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topologically speaking, any two norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent in that they induce the same topology. So, if you only care about topological properties, you may choose whatever norm you want. The Euclidean norm is often annoying during calculations, and some norms like the maximum norm are much more convenient.

However, things start to change when you step into infinite-dimensional spaces: different norms may induce different topologies. Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, $C[0,1]$ is complete with the sup-norm, but not complete in the $L^2$ norm: its completion is the Lebesgue space $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: The first paragraph is on point. In analysis, we often don’t deal with equalities (as much as we would like to), but rather inequalities…which essentially means in the large, we’re dealing with topological aspects of the problem. So equivalence of norms means we can choose the one most convenient for the purpose at hand. The times when we care about the exact choice of norm is for instance when we ‘set the scale’, for example with the usual inner product, the box $[0,1]^n$ has side lengths $1$, and is assigned Lebesgue measure $1$, and isometries (of this inner product) preserve measure etc.